# Unable to install the react developer tools extension on chrome, site shows a 404 error

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Here's the official link: [React Developer Tools Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/react-developer-tools/fmkadmapgofadopljbjfkapdkoienihi?hl=en)

Comment: It's gone for me too, and all the links on other websites also 404. There is nothing we can do here. I would recommend reaching out to the Chrome Store or the extension developers.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is not a programming question. We can't do anything with 3rd party websites.

Answer (score 3):

There was a bug so it was taken down to prevent spreading the bug in working installs.

https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/24549